# How to export from Powerpoint to PDF on MAC without creating a gigantic PDF?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, office-for-mac

When I export a 5mb pptx to pdf using powerpoint for Mac I get a 30mb PDF.
Using the **Compress Pictures** option form powerpoint doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 – Compress pictures in PowerPoint

- From the **File** menu choose **Compress Pictures**, Choose Email as the picture quality and save the file.
- Check the new pptx file size, it should have reduced a little

Step 2 – Change quality preferences in PowerPoint
 - Click on the **PowerPoint** menu, between the Apple logo and File
   menu and choose **Preferences**

[Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OaRw.png)

- Choose the **General** option listed under **Authoring and Proofing Tools**

[General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60viq.png)

- Select the drop down for Print Quality, set the desired quality to
  Low.

[Print Quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Kya.png)

- Export to PDF as usual and the file size will now be much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the PPT file using Keynote.
2. Modify some: font size etc.
3. Export as PDF with "quality of image: high".

The size of PDF converted using Keynote is mostly same with that of PPT, without downgrading the quality of images.

It is no doubt that there is a problem in the conversion process of PowerPoint for MAC.